# A special looping query

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, loops, for-loop

I am reading an excel using .NET and need to perform certain checks on that excel.
The excel example is as below:

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC

1001    Null    10
1001    W101    5
1001    W102    4
1001    W103    2

1002    Null    12
1002    W104    5
1002    W105    3

1003    W106    5
1003    W107    2
```

The requirement is as follows:

If there is a `Null` entry in `ColumnB`, then I need to compare the values under `ColumnC`,i.e. the sum of the values(5,4,2 as against the values W101, W102, W103) should be equal to 10(value against Null), if not then write an error in a log file.

```
My problem is that the there can be n values in ColumnC, how to loop against it.
```

In the above excel, the values corresponding to 1001 (`ColumnA`) are 4 in number whereas, the values corresponding to 1002, 1003 (`ColumnA`) are 3 and 2 in number respectively. 
How to write a generic logic for it, I am not able to understand.

Below is the code which I have written, but it will work only when I have 4 values corresponding to 1001 in ColumnA.

```
FileStream file = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
IExcelDataReader obj = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(file);//uses a 3rd party library

obj.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
DataSet ds = obj.AsDataSet();

DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (dt.Rows[i][1].ToString() == "Null")
    {
        double a = (double)dt.Rows[i][2];
        double x = (double)dt.Rows[i + 1][2];
        double y = (double)dt.Rows[i + 2][2];
        double z = (double)dt.Rows[i + 3][2];

        if (a != (x+ y + z))
        {
            Response.Write("Mismatch in row: " + dt.Rows[i + 1][1]);
            Response.Write("<br/>");
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I have used a 3rd party library to read the excel and convert it into a `DataSet`.

Answer (score 0):

The following query will get the results you need:

Test data used:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("A", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("B", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("C", typeof(int)));

dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1001", "Null", 10 });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1001", "W101", 5 });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1001", "W102", 4 });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1001", "W103", 1 });

dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1002", "Null", 12 });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1002", "W104", 5 });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1002", "W105", 3 });

dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1003", "W106", 5 });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1003", "W107", 2 });
```

LINQ:

```
var result =
    dt
    .AsEnumerable()
    // Group by the A-column.
    .GroupBy(r => (string)r["A"])
    // Get only those groups where the first item in the B-column is 'Null':
    .Where(g => g.FirstOrDefault(r => (string)r["B"] == "Null") != null)
    // Get only those groups where the sum of the items of the C-column 
    // after the first one is different from the first item: 
    .Where(g => (int)g.First()["C"] != g.Skip(1).Sum(r => (int)r["C"]))
    .ToList();
```

The result will contain rows groupped by the A-column that have invalid sums. If you are not interested in the actaul rows but only if they are valid then put `.Any()` in place of `.ToList()`.

---

If you don't use a `"Null"` `string`s but a *real* `null` like:

```
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1001", null, 10 });
```

you'll need to exchange the first `Where` to:

```
.Where(g => g.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Field<string>("B") == null) != null)
```

Comment: I wasn't sure whether the `Null` is a `string` or a _real_ `null` so I used strings in this example. You might have to change it to `null` in the `FirstOrDefault` that checks this.

Comment: It might be written as "Null" or maybe an empty string. I will take care of that.